# How can I specify the WE8MSWIN1252 encoding in Perl?

Tags: perl, encoding

I am using Perl and want to encode my strings using the following encoding : WE8MSWIN1252

I tried

```
$output =encode('WE8MSWIN1252',$string)
```

but its throwing error .

any idea how to specifiy this encoding WE8MSWIN1252 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WE8MSWIN1252` is Oracle's designation for [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

```perl
use Encode qw( encode );

my $bytes = encode('Windows-1252', $ucp);    # aka 'cp-1252' aka 'cp1252'
```

`$ucp` is expected to be decoded text aka a string of Unicode Code Points.

Comment: The codes of all encodings can be found at https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode::Supported.